# geocoding is not work on mobile

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Hi in mobile application I want to get address from latlong. I am using following url to get this;

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.9939817,72.8312086&sensor=true
```

on computer browser it works perfectly but when I tried it on mobile application i got response as:

```
{"results":[],"status":"REQUEST_DENIED"}
```

why is it so any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you double check that you have `&sensor=true` appended to the request?

( Asking because `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.9939817,72.8312086` would give you the exact response )

Comment: yes I have &sensor=true. I also tried with &sensor=false, but still same response.

Comment: the only other explanation is that your IP address of the phone running the app is blocked by Google, but this seems unlikely. Maybe it's an encoding problem and you are sending `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.9939817,72.8312086&amp;sensor=true`. If you found out already, let me know too :)

Comment: sure, I would just need the Java code that does the request not the whole app.